# How to write SQL command in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a project about searching database with given statements from a Windows form but I couldn't write the correct command for searching SQL. My code:

```
int? value;
if (this.textBox2.Text == "" || this.textBox2.Text == null)
    value = null;
else
    value = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox2.Text);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        @"SELECT * 
          FROM Billing 
            INNER JOIN Payment ON Payment.payment_id = Billing.billing_type 
            INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.customer_id = Billing.billing_customer
          WHERE  billing_id like '%" + textBox5.Text.ToString() + "%' 
            AND billing_type like '%" + comboBox2.SelectedValue + "%'
            AND Billing.billing_cost > " + value + "", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

The problem is that when I enter 3000 to `textBox2` (I controlled that it is reading 3000) searching is not working and display nothing. Also there is no exception thrown.

Did I write the command or not?

Comment: I think reader should include what error from sql you get.

Comment: Hard to tell without SQL Data. This looks suspicious: "Payment.payment_id = Billing.billing_type". Also watch out for sql insertions.

Comment: @KAYA you're sure theres data when Billing.billing_cost is >3000?

Comment: Yeap, I am sure , I looked the data value from converting, but there is no error in  "Payment.payment_id = Billing.billing_type" because I can display datas with this code.

Comment: What you're doing are joins with filters so if you get no records when running the query and there's no error, the most obvious cause would be that no record complies the condition. Take into account that inner join requires matching on both left and right tables.

Comment: Bobby Tables would not approve this select statement.

Comment: payment_id implies that what is the billing type, and others just get the data which customer has this billing , there is no relation with searching

Comment: @KAYA did you put a breakpoint, get the query string and try running you query with these parameters in Management Studio? This will tell you if there's a problem with the query itself or it's something with .Net.

Comment: KAYA - go and read about "SQL Injection". Do it now. It's that important!

Comment: I will do, @derloopkat. And also I will read SQL Injection , thanks :/

Comment: better to use mysqli, it's more secure, injects without showing the structure of data to would be hackers.

Comment: @TheGeorgeL How do you propose using `mysqli` with SQL Server?

Comment: @Kaya That can be due to your inner join some side of your inner join is null

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen oops, i said a stupid and thought they said mysql instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using parameters instead :

```
string query =  @"SELECT * 
          FROM Billing 
            INNER JOIN Payment ON Payment.payment_id = Billing.billing_type 
            INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.customer_id = Billing.billing_customer
          WHERE  billing_id like '%" + textBox5.Text.ToString() + "%' 
            AND billing_type like '%" + comboBox2.SelectedValue + "%'
            AND Billing.billing_cost > @value", connection);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@value",SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@value"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox2.Text);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Taken from [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: thank you but it warns me that @ID is not found and still not working

Comment: @KAYA sorry, corrected my answer, should've been `@value`

Comment: it warns again .. "Additional information: The parameterized query '(@value int)SELECT *   FROM Billing  INNER JOIN Payment ON Payme' expects the parameter '@value', which was not supplied"

Comment: @KAYA That usually happens when the supplied parameter is null.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
"select * From Billing INNER JOIN Payment ON Payment.payment_id = Billing.billing_type 
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.customer_id = Billing.billing_customer
where billing_id like '%'+'" + textBox5.Text + "'+'%' 
    and billing_type like '%'+'" + comboBox2.SelectedValue + "'+'%' 
    and Billing.billing_cost > " + value
```

1. Use char `'` on both before and after the symbol `%`
2. Tips. Never convert a data to same datatype. MSDN says it will reduce the speed speed of execution upto 7 times than exact coding. mentioning about your use of `textBox5.Text.ToString()`. Its wrong because its already a string.

Comment: @KAYA I have edited. Please retry. I got answer 
-
[Click here to see a snap of your answer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7qBAOThvb7zUV9vX002MkMzV0k)

Comment: downvote reason: this post ignores the biggest problem of the OP code, leaving the sql code still vulnerable to Sql injection attacks.

Comment: @ZoharPeled feel sad
i Know this is not a gud way as a developer. But just read KAYAs comments on his Qst. **I will read SQL Injection** as a reply to ones Qst **go and read about "SQL Injection". Do it now. It's that important!**. I think he is a biggner and try to develop a very small application. and i just correct his Code. Thts all

Comment: I tried from sql and write again correctly by using your solution but not working :/  @JishnuKM